# how to use output of helper method as value in haml hash?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml, helper

I have a button and I want to set its onClick attribute dynamically each page load.  I want to use application_helper to give it a custom javascript every time.  It seems difficult to do because the Javascript is going to need access to stuff that only the ruby has access to.  I wanted to build up a custom javascript with the application_helper module and yield the result of calling the helper method as the value to the onClick key in the Haml hash:

In application.html.haml:

```
%button{class: "user_navigation_menu_item", onClick: =  gimme_my_custom_javascript}
```

In application_helper,rb:

```
def gimme_my_custom_javascript
  javascript = "function(){"
  javascript +="alert('yo!');"
  javascript+="}"
end
```

Haml is yelling at me: 'unexpected "="'

How do I do what I am trying to do?

Thank you

Comment: Note that it is better to programmatically assign your JavaScript handlers through code, rather than as attributes mixed into your content HTML.

Comment: Like kick off a script onDocumentLoad that assigns functionality to all the things?

Comment: Yes, or on a window/load event, or just putting your script at the bottom of the page where all elements have already been created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just get rid of the `=` and it should work:

```
%button{class: "user_navigation_menu_item", onClick: gimme_my_custom_javascript}
```